# Displaying a Single Element Array (via Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a function that returns an array of results which I display by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in Excel.

If I have multiple values (say 3), that are expanded into a range of length 10, it will display the 3 values followed by `#N/A` for the remaining 7.

If I have only one value in the array, it will display the same value across the entire range.

How do I get Excel to have the same behavior with only one element?

Comment: **Help us to help you.** Post your code.

Comment: Never produce a 1-array? Can you add an N/A to the end?

Comment: What does *'doing a Ctrl+Shift+Enter'* have to do with VBA? It sounds like you need to wrap [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) around an array formula.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the **1-element array** is *ary()*:

```
Public Function WhatEver()
   Dim ary(1 To 1) As String
   Dim bry As Variant, rN As Long

   rN = Application.Caller.Rows.Count
   ReDim bry(1 To rN, 1 To 1)

   ary(1) = "Whatever"
   bry(1, 1) = ary(1)

   For i = 2 To rN
      bry(i, 1) = "#N/A"
   Next i
   WhatEver = bry
End Function
```

[image]

*Based on Eric's suggestion.*